# Equation for solving pharmacokinetic parameters

Tags: functions

I am getting stuck at this level. I need to solve $\alpha$, $\beta$ and $\delta$ in terms of $\omega_i$

Given: 
$$\alpha + \beta + \delta = \omega_1+\omega_2+\omega_3+\omega_4+\omega_5$$
$$\alpha\beta\delta = \omega_3\omega_5\omega_1 $$
$$\alpha\beta+\alpha\delta+\beta\delta=\omega_1\omega_3+\omega_4\omega_3+\omega_1\omega_5+\omega_3\omega_5+\omega_5\omega_2$$

These will solve pharmacokinetic coefficients.

Answer (score 0):

The RHS are all known in terms of the $\omega_i$ so for now let's leave them as a shorthand A,B and C. Plug back in at the end. Let's call the left hand sides $e_1 (\alpha,\beta,\delta)$, $e_3 (\alpha,\beta,\delta)$ and $e_2 (\alpha,\beta,\delta)$. That is because they are the elementary symmetric polynomials in those variables. By the main property of elementary symmetric polynomials we have

$$
(y-\alpha)(y-\beta)(y-\gamma)=y^3 - e_1 y^2 + e_2 y - e_3=y^3 - A y^2 + C y - B
$$

so we know the coefficients of a degree 3 polynomial in terms of $\omega_i$ and we want to figure out the roots $\alpha$ $\beta$ and $\delta$. But since this is a cubic polynomial, we can actually solve this in [closed form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_function#General_solution_to_the_cubic_equation_with_real_coefficients). That is we get $\alpha$, $\beta$ and $\delta$ in terms of $A$,$B$ and $C$ which are then in terms of the $\omega_i$.

Remark: of course the ambiguity of permuting the names is still there.